# online notes on symmetric spaces

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, symmetry

Can anyone suggest some good online lecture notes on symmetric spaces? 
I am interested in reading from Helgason, which is a very tough book to read. So I am searching for some places where the treatment is leisurely.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ones which seem to fit the bill:
http://www.math.uni-augsburg.de/~eschenbu/symspace.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4159

http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/notes.html